# Equivalent perl Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, perl

Perl uses $` to return everything before the matched string and $' to return everything after the matched string. I was wondering if there is something similar in python or any work around to get it. Thanks

Comment: The work around is to split the string with your pattern, but if you hope to use the parts for a replacement string you can't do that. you can use capturing groups instead: `(.*?)yourpattern(.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you collect a `MatchObject` from the result of a `search` operation, you can use its contents to build the equivalent substrings to Perl's `` $` ``  and `$'`

Like this

```
import re

ss = '123/abc'

match = re.search('/', ss)

print ss[:match.start()]
print match.group()
print ss[match.end():]
```

**output**

```
123
/
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `re.split` command to split the input according to a particular regex and then get the string before the match from index 0 of returned list and the string after the match from index 1.

```
>>> word = 'foo'
>>> re.split(re.escape(word), 'barfoobuz', maxsplit=1)
['bar', 'buz']
```

By adding `maxsplit=1` parameter, the above `re.split` function will do splitting only one time according to the characters which matches the given pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I omitted to say that I want to use the said operations in a lexer, so I don't know exactly when to split a string although the grammar is finite and unambiguous

Comment: what do you mean by said operations? is this won't satisfy your needs then provide an example along with expected output.